# QTP Addin - Object is not being recognised

Tags: object, web, add-in, qtp, identification

QTP doesn't recognize item when I disable some add-ins which was checked when I added them in to the repository

Note: I actually selected all the add in's when I added the objects into repository - .Net, JAVA, Oracle, Siebel, SAP, Web Services, Silverlight, ActiveX(I know I am a Noob). When I just select Web right now and run the script, it's unable to recognize the object and when I add the object again(with only Web checked), it's being added as a new object and is being recognized when I run it.

So my question is what is the relationship of an object with respect to add in? How does it go on to affect the property of the same object?

Comment: Does the object belong to one of the addins that is unloaded? Please give the description and type of the object that isn't recognised and the type and description of the object that is created instead of said object when recording only with Web.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I didn't record these object but added them to Object repository through Object spy. When I disable all the addin with only web and Active X enabled, the QTP takes a long time to recognize the initial browser object and it ends up not finding the same. If I enable all the addin, it works a gem. I have re-added the  Objects into Object repository for it to work only when I have Web and Active X selected but I would like to know what's causing the trouble

Answer (score 0):

### **Add-Ins are Collections of Pre-Defined Object Types**

The add-in contains built-in property sets for a specific group of related UI objects. This helps QTP identify the runtime objects more effectively for a specific type of application.

For instance, it's quite predictable that browser-based applications will be using the standard HTML elements, so the basic web objects (i.e. Page, Frame, WebButton, WebList) have already been defined in advance inside the Web add-in.

### **The Evil in Enabling All Add-Ins**

Most likely, you're facing the issue because all add-ins were enabled during recording. QTP had the option to choose from any of the pre-defined objects in all of those add-ins as it sees fit. You could have ended up with an object repository that's a hybrid of object types found in multiple add-ins.

We faced this similar issue before where a web button (i.e. html input type="button") was recorded as a `SAPWebButton`. That's because all add-ins were enabled during recording and no one noticed. It worked fine until we disabled all other add-ins, except for the Web add-in. Since the Web add-in only knows about a `WebButton` **not** a `SAPWebButton`, this resulted into identification problems.

### Prevention and Fix

The correct approach is to decide which add-in is most appropriate for your application type before recording, enable it and disable the rest.

You will have to manually update the problematic object via Update Run Mode. If there's too much, you'd be better off recording from scratch.

Comment: Thanks for your input Jops. I actually didn't record these object but added them to Object repository through Object spy. So not sure what the actual problem is?

Comment: @EnthusiasticLearner Yup, it can happen via Object Spy too. As long as you have all add-ins enabled, QTP will try to match the object you clicked to any of the built-in classes available. Try to check what class is being detected when you click your object. If you site specific examples, I may be able to help you more.

Comment: It's not detecting the Browser.  I tried to add the same object with and without the said addins. I was able to see some Properties added in the "Identification" section. But there were no values for these extra properties which were seen when the said addins were enabled.

Comment: Text = "Random Text"
Systemutil.Run "iexplore", "google.com"
Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebEdit("GoogleSearch").Set Text
Browser("Google").Page("Google").WebButton("Google Search").Click Above is a test. I added the Google search button and search text objects after selecting all the addins. I tried to run the same script after selecting just the Web addin and it doesn't work

Comment: Please disable all add-ins except the Web add-in. Create a new Test, add the objects, then run.